# Test cases are not running in parallel when try to run with Cucumber JSON reports?

Tags: karate

I have 320 API test cases which are taking more time to run sequentially in CI CD Pipeline. However i have modified runner class to run test cases in parallel with 50 threads as below.

```
Results results = Runner.parallel(getClass(), 50, "target/surefire-reports");
```

After execution am am getting result in XML and in JSON format but i want that report in html format so am planning to use cucumber JSON reports and for that i have added below code in runner class as below:

```
KarateStats stats = CucumberRunner.parallel(getClass(), 1, karateOutputPath); // generateReport(karateOutputPath); // assertTrue("there are scenario failures", stats.getFailCount() == 0);
```

Comment: KarateStats stats = CucumberRunner.parallel(getClass(), 1, karateOutputPath);
//        generateReport(karateOutputPath);
//        assertTrue("there are scenario failures", stats.getFailCount() == 0);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Karate -- Parallel execution Failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54538060/karate-parallel-execution-failing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be quite confused. The HTML reporting is a separate step from the parallel runner. Please read the documentation here carefully, it will answer your questions:

https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo#example-report